# 'SuperMarioBrosEnv' object has no attribute 'render_mode'

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, stable-baselines

I am practicing the machine learning by following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eeYqJ0uBKE

While Im following what the video did, I encounter a bug. Can someone help me with this ?

P/S: I'm coding on Jupyter notebook on VSCODE using macbook

Thank you for your help!

My code:

```
from gym.wrappers import GrayScaleObservation
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStack, DummyVecEnv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

env = gym_super_mario_bros.make('SuperMarioBros-v0')
env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)
env = GrayScaleObservation(env, keep_dim=True)
env = DummyVecEnv(\[lambda: env\])
```

The error shown:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1.ipynb Cell 12 in ()
2 env = JoypadSpace(env, SIMPLE_MOVEMENT)
3 env = GrayScaleObservation(env, keep_dim=True)
\----\> 4 env = DummyVecEnv(\[lambda: env\])

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py:30, in DummyVecEnv.__init__(self, env_fns)
29 def __init__(self, env_fns: List\[Callable\[\[\], gym.Env\]\]):
\---\> 30     self.envs = \[\_patch_env(fn()) for fn in env_fns\]
31     if len(set(\[id(env.unwrapped) for env in self.envs\])) != len(self.envs):
32         raise ValueError(
33             "You tried to create multiple environments, but the function to create them returned the same instance "
34             "instead of creating different objects. "
(...)
39             "Please read https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/1151 for more information."
40         )

File /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/dummy_vec_env.py:30, in (.0)
29 def __init__(self, env_fns: List\[Callable\[\[\], gym.Env\]\]):
\---\> 30     self.envs = \[_patch_env(fn()) for fn in env_fns\]
31     if len(set(\[id(env.unwrapped) for env in self.envs\])) != len(self.envs):
32         raise ValueError(
33             "You tried to create multiple environments, but the function to create them returned the same instance "
34             "instead of creating different objects. "
...
227 if name.startswith("_"):
228     raise AttributeError(f"attempted to get missing private attribute '{name}'")
\--\> 229 return getattr(self.env, name)

AttributeError: 'SuperMarioBrosEnv' object has no attribute 'render_mode'
```

P/S: I'm coding on Jupyter notebook on VSCODE using macbook